# mysql: multiple indexes advice

Tags: mysql, performance, select, indexing, insert

I have a single table where I need to query based on 4 columns a,b,c,d
The most common query will be a select based on all 4 columns at the same time, however I need to be able to search quickly for each of the columns taken separately, or also combinations of them (e.g. a&b, a&d, b&c&d and so on).
Shall I create an index for every combination? or it's better to have only an index for a&b&c&d and one for a, one for b, one for c, one for d? in this last case a query that matches only a&b for example will be sped up because both a and be have an index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to satisfy all the combinations with an index, you need the following:

```
(a, b, c, d)
(a, b, d)
(a, c, d)
(a, d)
(b, c, d)
(b, d)
(c, d)
d
```

You don't need other combinations because any prefix of an index is also an index. The first index will be used for queries that test just `a`, `a&b`, `a&b&c`, so you don't need indexes for those combinations.

Whether you really need all these indexes depends on how much data you have. It's possible that just having indexes on each column will narrow down the search sufficiently that you don't need indexes on the combinations. The only real way to tell is by benchmarking the performance of your applications. The indexes take up disk space and memory, so trying to create all possible indexes can cause problems of its own; you need to determine if the need is strong enough.

Comment: RIght now it's impossible to say how big the table will be, but I can guess 500k for a normal table, and several millions for the biggest ones. The data itself is not huge, I have 22 columns, 9 are decimal, one is text, the others are tinyint, and the indexes will be tinyint. So 8 indexes could be too much?

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is that a "range" is only useful as the last item in an index:

```
WHERE x=2 AND y>5   -- INDEX(x,y) is useful; INDEX(y,x) only uses `y`
WHERE x=2 AND y BETWEEN 11 AND 22 -- ditto
WHERE x=2 AND s LIKE 'foo%'  -- ditto
```

Another thing:  "flags" (true/false, etc) are useless to index by themselves.  They can be somewhat useful in combination:

```
WHERE published=1 AND ...
```

Also, order matters in the `INDEX`, but not in the `WHERE`:  Suppose you have `INDEX(a,b)`:

```
WHERE a=1 AND b=2 -- good index
WHERE b=2 AND a=1 -- equally good
WHERE a=1         -- the index is good
WHERE b=2         -- the index is useless
```

If some column is always a range (such as a date), it gets messier.  For optimal indexing two indexes are needed here:

```
WHERE d BETWEEN ...  -- needs INDEX(d)
WHERE a=1 AND d BETWEEN ...  -- needs INDEX(a,d)
```

So, I might do these:

- Make all 2-column combinations of a,b,c,d -- This would be 6 combinations if nothing is involved in "ranges".  I would be sure to vary which col starts the indexes:  ab, bc, cd, da, ac, db
- Turn on the slowlog to see what is not being well indexed.
- Log the *actual* combinations that people use.  Some combinations *will be* very rarely used.  Get rid of the indexes that are useless.

[*More*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) on understanding index creation.

Comment: The columns I want to index are kind of flags, three of them store simple integers, one could be a boolean because I have only two possible values, do you mean that this last column would make a useless index because of this?

Comment: @JamesBiffi - "last column useless" -- no.  By using only 2 columns, I keep the number of indexes to a civilized number.  To do all combos of 4, 24 indexes would be needed -- probably too many.  The 8 that Barmar listed works assuming all tests are `=`, not ranges, maybe not `INs`.

Comment: @JamesBiffi - it might help to have the actual `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, with clues of the semantics of the 4 columns.  There may be other 'tricks' we can play based on an understanding of the problem set.  Example:  Whenever you test for `b`, you also test for `c`.

Comment: Thanks both answers were helpful!