# mysql: indexes in a delete query

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I've asked a suggestion on indexes and select queries here
[mysql: multiple indexes advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44293556/mysql-multiple-indexes-advice)

Now I'd like to focus on a slightly different issue: I also have to delete lots of rows at the same time (in case you ask, my db supports a map creation tool, so you have lots of inserts and deletes, and re-inserts etc. as many as the user adds and removes map elements).
Are indexes used in deletes also? I imagined that I could copy table1 onto a new table2 excluding all the elements not being deleted (so I use a select), drop the old table1, and then copy table2 in table1, this way table1 ends up with only the rows it needs. Of course if a delete operation uses indexes the same way a select does this is useless. I stress that very large tables might reach millions of rows.
What is the best approach?

edit: this is the show create table

| map   | CREATE TABLE `map` (
  `px` decimal(7,3) NOT NULL,
  `py` decimal(7,3) NOT NULL,
  `pz` decimal(7,3) NOT NULL,
  `rx` decimal(7,3) NOT NULL,
  `ry` decimal(7,3) NOT NULL,
  `rz` decimal(7,3) NOT NULL,
  `sx` decimal(7,3) NOT NULL,
  `sy` decimal(7,3) NOT NULL,
  `sz` decimal(7,3) NOT NULL,
  `a` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `b` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `c` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `d` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `e` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `f` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `g` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `h` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `i` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `j` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `k` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `l` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `m` text,
  KEY `a` (`a`),
  KEY `b` (`b`),
  KEY `c` (`c`),
  KEY `d` (`d`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place where you can get suggestions as to how to write your code. Think about what you want to do, plan about how you want your code to work, what the most efficient way is and get to coding. Use paper and pen, be creative. Don't choose the easy way. Again, this is not a place where others will tell you how to write code. IF you have a question that you think might help others in the future, then edit and repost. Otherwise I would advice you to delete this question.

Comment: I disagree that my request is about coding, in fact I can handle my code, my db is what is giving me some headaches, my questions are about very high level concepts and best practices.

Comment: Ignoring the indexing issue (for the moment), let's see what the `DELETE` looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple techniques for dealing with a million rows being "updated".

1. If it is an complete replacement, build a new table, then swap (`RENAME TABLE`).
2. If the "update" needs to `INSERT` or `UPDATE`...  That is, some rows are new, some need minor modifications, then look at `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`
3. If you need some combination of the two, plus `DELETEing` some of the rows, it gets messier, but it can probably be done in a very few SQL statements, no looping.  `CREATE` and populate (`LOAD DATA`?) the change set; perform a multi-table `DELETE`; perform a `INSERT ... SELECT .. LEFT JOIN ..` to copy in "new" rows; do IODKU or multi-table `UPDATE` do do the `UPDATEs`.  I discuss some of that [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization).

I don't fully grok what you need to do.  Which of these techniques sounds close?  Can you rephrase your requirements closer to what I propose?  Perhaps then I can be more specific.  It would probably be useful to include `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and point out the column(s) that play a role in deciding what to insert/delete/update.

And, yes, `INDEXes` are useful for `DELETEs` and `UPDATEs`.

Comment: I've added the show create table. Relevant columns are a,b,c,d where the matches are being made, those columns when all matched can define with extreme precision the group of map data I want to delete. Columns px and pz are matched against ranges (they represent an object's position on the map). My concern is to be able to delete whole ranges of objects as defined by a,b,c,d then the db will search inside px and pz ranges. BTW it will never be a complete replacement nor an update, the data will either be inserted or deleted.

Comment: Will you be using `px = constant`?  or `px BETWEEN .. and ..`?

Comment: I'll test ranges so it will be px >= "left limit" and px<= "right limit"; the same applies for pz which will be tested against bottom and top limits.

Comment: No index can handle two ranges at the same time.  Indexes are 1-dimensional; it sounds like you have a 2D problem.  For performance in a 2D world (but not 3D or higher), see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng

Comment: What do you mean? px and pz will not be indexed, only a,b,c,d will. If I make a select by specifying a,b,cd, then I guess the db will scan all the filtered results in a classic way for px and pz values.

Comment: To discuss deletes, let's see a typical `DELETE ...`.  And if you need to delete based on various combinations of a,b,c,d, be sure to state that; else my reply will focus on the index needed for the one `DELETE` you provide.

Comment: Sure: delete from map where a=0 and b=1 and c=2 and d in (0,1,2,3) and px >= -10 and px <= 10 and pz >=-10 and pz <=10

Comment: `INDEX(a,b,c,d,px)` -- `a,b,c` need to be _first_, in any order.

Comment: Do I really have to index px also? I think that by specifying a,b,c,d I'll narrow down the lookup to a few thousands rows, at that point I don't care if there's a scan on the resulting rows.

Comment: Fine; stop with (a,b,c,d).  Not knowing the distribution of values, etc, I cannot make an argument for or against doing otherwise.  But note, this is a _single, composite_, index _not_ 4 (or 5) _single-column_ indexes.